# Why does Flask-SocketIO have `http` protocol instead of `ws`?

Tags: python, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I was trying to implement a WebSocket server using this Flask extension:
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

I see that the client is using socketio like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
    });
</script>
```

Why is it using `http://` while it is supposed to be WebSocket server (using `ws://`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part of the protocol that Socket.IO is interested in is the `s` part, i.e. `http(s), ws(s)`, i.e. whether the connection is supposed to be encrypted. Except for that the protocol is ignored and Socket.IO tries multiple different protocols (websockets, long polling over http, etc.) in order to establish the connection. Depending on what the server supports.

Comment: So the `Flask-SocketIO` on the back-end is only compatible with `socketio` on the front-end? I mean I couldn't use the built-in `WebSocket()`?

Comment: @doodoroma Yes, SocketIO is a layer on top of either ws or http. You can't just use a websocket connection unless you know the protocol.

Comment: I have _Aha_ moments occasionally, this was one of them, thanks. The doc was not clear 100%